# Open a markdown linked file in a specific app

Tags: macos, applescript, markdown, automator

I don't know if this is possible. With Automator pre-defined Actions it doesn't work. But maybe with a AppleScript?

I've a .jpg file in a folder and a Markdown link points to that file. When I click on the link, the file opens in Preview. What I want is that when I right-click on that file i can select a Service (Automator Quick Action) to open that file in Photoshop. Is that possible with AppleScript (which can be used inside Automator)?

Comment: Not sure I get you. Right now you should be able top right-click a  jpeg and `open with` any suitable app including photoshop.

Comment: I wanna open that file when click or right-click the Markdown Link to that file.

Comment: I'm skeptical that you can do this, as typically, any form of alias is just pointing to the target file. Conceivably, you could pass the link's url to a script which opens the file. As an alternative, would setting the jpeg's default app to photoshop make a difference?

Comment: Setting PS as the default app would work. But i don't wanna open every jpeg in PS. That's the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure specifically what a 'markdown link' looks like but if you can use it to get a standard applescript file reference (e.g. alias, posix file) then applescript could set the default app for only that particular image.